# How do I allow a user to enter a value into a report and then use this value as a parameter for a linked report?

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, reporting, ssrs-2008-r2

I want to make a report where, after loading and rendering, the user gets a textbox where they can enter in a value. Then, I want to add a link to another report where it takes the value from the textbox and uses it as a parameter. Is this possible?

Comment: get a textbox after report is loading?

Answer (score 1):

It's not elegant but....

You can do this but you would have to add the text box as a normal parameter in your first report.

You would then add the second report as a subreport (*see comments at end) and have it hidden if your textbox parameter is empty. You main report would only be visible if the textbox parameter is NOT empty.

So first run the report shows the main report with the subreport hidden, user then fills in the textbox parameter and hits view report, this will re-run the report but as the textbox now has a value, the main report will be hidden and the subreport visible.

You don't have to use subreports, you could just build two distinct parts of the report to show/hide but subreports might make it easier to manage and faster.

Comment: The critical part that I am looking for is for the user to be able to fill a value into the report body, i.e. not in the regular parameters at the top of the report. So imagine that a user opens my report. Next, he hits "View Report". The reports loads some stuff. ***Then*** he writes a value into a textbox on the report.

Comment: What I suggested will do that but as I said, not elegant. There is no way to add any input textboxes in the report body itself.